# Не отображаются стили css на другой одинаковой странице html

Tags: html, css, gulp, scss

Пишу многостраничный сайт с помощью `gulp` и `scss(vs code)`, есть папка `app`, в которой вложена папка `scss`, внутри файл `index.html`, в котором все корректно подключено и работает при открытии браузера.
Создаю в той же папке второй файл `about.html`(копирую все содержимое из `index` и вставляю в `about`) , пишу ссылку `<a class="_name_" href="../app/scss/about.html">About</a>` из `index` в `about`, она работает, но после перехода на вторую страницу пропадают стили css, хотя `html` код остается, в чем может быть причина ? Если нужны какие-то фрагменты кода, то могу прикрепить

Comment: Вопрос исчерпан